# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append' - Python Function "improve average"

Tags: python

***Hello everyone, this is my first post overhere so please let me know if there is something wrong with this post.
I'm trying to improve some values of a list if that value is lower than the average of the list and what I tried to do is this:***

```
def improve(list,average):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i]<average:
            list[i].append(average) #This line gives me the error.

list=[10.50,11.40,20.50,9.30,5.00]
sum=0
average=float(0)
for i in list:
    sum=sum+i
    average=sum/len(list)
print(list)
improve(list,average)
print("improved list=",list)
```

***And I got the error "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'", I'm sure the code is right but if I can't append float things, what I can or should do?
Thank you so much everyone and I'll be being active overhere since I started stuying a Degree in System and I'll have tons of questions or doubts.***

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? Also, what is the improve() function? There seems to be information missing.

Comment: I think you want `list[i] = list[i] + average`. You seem to be treating `append` as addition. It isn't.

Comment: `list[i].append(average)` your error is here you are trying to append value to float value present at that position. If you mean to insert that postion you should use `list.insert(index,average)` or if you want to append to list do this `list.append(average)` or if you want to incremment the value at that postion use `list[i]+=average`

Comment: Hello everyone, I've edited the post because the first line was missing, my bad, i didnt know I had to put the first line under of the ´´´ and I've commented the line that gives me the error

Comment: I think you probably don't want `average = sum / len(list)` in the for loop...

Comment: @syohey That's true, I hadn't noticed it and I already edited it but still doesn't work

Comment: Again, would you please explain what is the purpose of your code?

Comment: Tangentially, it is an arbitrary thing to change the values how you are trying to change them (which isn't very clear in the question). You describe it as "improving" them -- but it seems more like vandalism to me. You are losing information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might be looking for...

```
def improve_list(ls, average):
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        if ls[i] < average:
            ls[i] = average
    return ls # Returns the improved list.

ls = [10.50, 11.40, 20.50, 9.30, 5.00]
total = 0.0
average = 0.0
for num in ls:
    total += num
average = total / len(ls)

print("Original list: {}".format(ls))
improved_list = improve_list(ls, average) # Stores the improved list in a variable.
print("Improved list: {}".format(improved_list))
```

Comment: Yes thank you!, I noticed I had to do it with "=" and not with append

Answer (score 0):

I think you believe `append()` would add both numbers, which is wrong. `append()` pushes a value to a list, that's the reason why you are getting the error: a float number is not a list, so it has no attribute `append`.

I believe the line you need is: `list[i] = list[i] + average`

Comment: Yes, thank you!, I just had to do list[i]=average lol